# Why does HTML stored in localStorage change when recalled and displayed in the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-mobile, local-storage

Sorry if this has been asked before, I've searched but couldn't find anything appropriately related...

I have a very simple site here that has 3 buttons:

1. Add Component
2. Save Current State
3. Restore Saved State

The **Add Component** button does exactly what I want which is to create a new simple ***collapse item*** within the
`<div data-role="collapsible-set" class="flow" id="collapsibleComponent"></div>` tags.

[image: Collapsible component created and added to the page properly]

Also, the **Save Current State**
`storeCurrentState();` button seems to capture the required code ***identically*** to what's being displayed (which is correct).

However, when I click the **Restore Saved State** button (run the `restorePriorState();` method), the code that is read from the localStorage and put back into the page is not consistent with the code that was saved. As a result I end up with a nested looking collapsed item like below...

[image: clustered mess]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>TutorialW3a</title>
        <link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.theme-1.3.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="jquery-mobile/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Header</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <div data-role="collapsible-set" class="flow" id="collapsibleComponent">
                    <!--New collapsible divs go here-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <button onclick="addCollapsibleComponent()">Add component</button>
            <button onclick="storeCurrentState()">Save current state</button>
            <button onclick="restorePriorState()">Restore saved state</button>
            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
                <h4>Footer</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
<script>
    //
    var collapsibleComponentContent = document.getElementById("collapsibleComponent");
    var collapsibleDiv;
    function addCollapsibleComponent() {
        //create div element
        collapsibleDiv = $('<div id="new" data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true"><h3>Heading</h3><p>Paragraph</p></div>"');
        //append new collapsible div to #collapsibleComponent
        $("#collapsibleComponent").append(collapsibleDiv);
        //collapse all collapsible divs
        $('div[data-role="collapsible"]').collapsible();
    }
    //
    function storeCurrentState() {
        collapsibleDiv = document.getElementById("new");
        localStorage.setItem("html_data", JSON.stringify(collapsibleComponentContent.innerHTML));
    }
    //
    function restorePriorState() {
        collapsibleComponentContent.innerHTML = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("html_data"));
        $("#new").collapsible();
    }
</script>
```

This is what is generated when a new collapsible component is created...

```
<div id="new" data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" class="ui-collapsible ui-collapsible-inset ui-collapsible-collapsed">
<h3 class="ui-collapsible-heading ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed">
    <a href="#" class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-up-c" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="left" data-theme="c"
        ><span class="ui-btn-inner"
            ><span class="ui-btn-text">Heading<span class="ui-collapsible-heading-status"> click to expand contents</span></span
            ><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span></span
        ></a
    >
</h3>
<div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-collapsible-content-collapsed" aria-hidden="true"><p>Paragraph</p></div>
```

And this is what is created when I reload...

```
<h3 class="ui-collapsible-heading ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed">
<a href="#" class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-up-c" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="left" data-theme="c"
    ><span class="ui-btn-inner"
        ><span class="ui-btn-text"
            ><a href="#" class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-up-c" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="left" data-theme="c"
                ><span class="ui-btn-inner"
                    ><span class="ui-btn-text">Heading<span class="ui-collapsible-heading-status"> click to expand contents</span></span
                    ><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span></span
                ></a
            ><span class="ui-collapsible-heading-status"> click to expand contents</span></span
        ><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span></span
    ></a
>
```

Comment: What do you mean non consistent ? you get totally different data on restore to what is saved ?

Comment: Yeah, it adds in spans that weren't there before and adds other classes to the div tags.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I have edited my original post to show the code that is generated and saved, then what is showing up after reloading the changes from local storage

Comment: I can not reproduce this issue. All seems to work fine for me.

Comment: How confusing?, I end up with it looking all nested like shown at https://i.stack.imgur.com/BU7iM.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking "Why", so here is the answer:

JQM is a mixed JS/CSS framework, i.e. the `widgets` are enhanced by JS and styled by CSS. After page initialization, the widgets (identified by the "`data-role`" tag) are enhanced by the framework by adding some nested elements (`div`, `span`), `pseudo-elements` (icons) and event handlers.

That said, in Your code You are saving the *enhanced* version of Your initial markup together with the `data-role` attribute, but You are saving only the *markup*, this means You won't save the JS `data` which will be created by the framework during the widget initialization. In short, You are saving only one half of the already enhanced widget.

The next time, the framework will find the `data-role` attribute again, but not the associated `data` object and by invoking `$("#new").collapsible();` You will end up with that double-nested markup.

More information:

You can take a look at the JQM widget object as follows:

```
$.data(document.getElementById("new"),"mobile-collapsible")
```

or:

```
$("#new").jqmData("mobile-collapsible")
```

There is more than one possible solution for Your task.

Maybe You can restore the initial un-enhanced markup:

```
$("#collapsibleComponent :jqmData(role='collapsible')").collapsible("destroy");
```

and save that:

```
localStorage.setItem("html_data", JSON.stringify($("#collapsibleComponent").html()));
```

Finally, You assumption that

> to capture the required code identically to what's being displayed is correct

is wrong.

Comment: thank you very much for your detailed explanation! That's a perfect answer as it has given me some clearly defined areas I need to learn more about... Thank you for pointing me in the right direction 

Comment: @Nathan: thanks for Your feedback! To get more help from the community, You may need to switch to the latest JQM version 1.4.5